# Storing values for CSS properties as variables in an external configuration file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way I could store values for CSS properties as variables like height/ width of an element as variables in config file so that the they can be easily maintained & there is no need to change css values of elements but just variables in an external configuration file.

Variables, mainly because if I resize an element & I want that the other elements should compensate for that change, I dont need to chnage all the values but just a single variable !?

Is it even possible ??

Comment: Have a look into LESS (CSS extension that allows things like variables): http://lesscss.org/

Comment: LESS is good, and so is [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Here's a good quick overview of [Sass and Compass](http://sonspring.com/journal/sass-for-designers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with standard CSS. It would be possible if you want to use JavaScript to apply style properties dynamically, but a simpler solution could be to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which is a CSS extension designed to do things exactly like this.

Here's an example:

```css
@myWidth: 100px;

#header {
  width: @myWidth;
}
#footer {
  width: @myWidth;
}
```

That get's "compiled" into plain old CSS by the LESS script:

```css
#header {
  width: 100px;
}
#footer {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Obviously, with such a small example there's little benefit, but when you're working with huge CSS files, it can make a massive difference. There are numerous other things that LESS brings to the table, so have a look through the documentation to get an idea of them all.